# how to relation all tables in database with one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that have tables , what I want is to make a report with all values in those tables , problem is every table has it's date what I want is to make a report that get data from date1 to date2 and get all data exactly , every table has data that didn't relate to other so the date in table will be another in other table, as I mention I want to make a report that contain all those tables data from date1 to date2.
I use php / mysql .

I will appreciate any advice and help.

Thanks .

EDIT :

example 
table person

```
id
name
address
date_from
date_to
```

table room

```
id 
room_no
date_from
date_to
```

but there is no relation between them all I want is to get data from those table between date1 and date2 that user will put to get the result like that

2017-10-10 to 2017-10-11

```
name    address     room_no
nader   agamy         44
```

This is an tiny example the data is huge and there is many tables and I want to collect them in one report based on the date that user start with and end with ..

Hope I delivered the problem good enough.

Comment: You need to add at least how a couple of the tables look and how you expect/want to get the data

Comment: @JimL thanks buddy , i add some new information may it help ,

Comment: you want to join table ?

Comment: i want to make something like this https://imgur.com/fJ1guMi i want to make the date constant and get the data like the image but as i mention in the question that every table has it's own date , so what's the solution ,

Answer (score 0):

The tables should have a relation in between them in order to get the output you want.

Comment: i want that but i want to make a table contain the dates of a year and make the other tables based on it as this report https://imgur.com/fJ1guMi

Comment: Do you have common dates in both the tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be helpful for you.
get the result from MYSQL table between two dates in every table in PHP. Those tables data from start date to end date in the MySQL tables.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$select_data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM first_table LEFT JOIN second_table ON
'first_table.id' = 'second_table.id' WHERE `first_table.date` BETWEEN '".$f_date."' AND '".$t_date."' AND `second_table.date` BETWEEN '".$first_date."' AND '".$second_date."'");
?>
```